# Sort an item in a list of tuples in the values of a dictionary with Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to sort the first item in a list of tuples in the value of a dictionary.

Here is my dictionary:

```
d = {'key_': (('2', 'a'), ('3', 'b'), ('4', 'c'), ('1', 'd'))}
```

I want the sorted output to look like this:

```
d2 = {'key_': (('1', 'd'), ('2', 'a'), ('3', 'b'), ('4', 'c'))}
```

I tried sorting the values to a new dictionary, but that doesn't work:

```
d2 = sorted(d.values(), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d.values()` return the list of all the values present within the dictionary. But here you want to sort the list which is present as value corresponding to `key_` key. So, you have to call the sorted function as:

```
# Using tuple as your example is having tuple instead of list
>>> d['key_'] = tuple(sorted(d['key_'], key=lambda x: x[0]))
>>> d
{'key_': (('1', 'd'), ('2', 'a'), ('3', 'b'), ('4', 'c'))}
```

Alternatively (not suggested), you may also directly sort the list without calling the `sorted` function as:

```
>>> d['key_'] = list(d['key_']).sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
{'key_': (('1', 'd'), ('2', 'a'), ('3', 'b'), ('4', 'c'))}
```

Comment: You don't really need a `key` in this case.

Comment: I know. But this is based on the user's sample input and his desired ouput

Comment: Note you can simplify this a bit by using an in-place sort: `d['key_'].sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`. Also, the value is a tuple in the example, not a list :)

Comment: Updated the answer. I missed the part that it is holding the tuple value. I just corrected the mistake OP was making. As you mentioned it is a tuple, your code won't work. In order to make it work, you have to do: `list(d['key_']).sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: @Karin, it's a list of tuples so the dictionary value is both :)